# Returning data based on id

Tags: php

I was trying to return data based on an ID, however, I have been running into some problems, I have tested it by manually putting in an ID which will return the values I would expect, when I attempted to do it, dynamically? I can't get it to return the relevant ID's, so I attempted to add the unique ID at the start of my block to see if that would help, it appeared to have changed nothing, where am I going wrong? OR is there a tutorial I can read more on to help me with this?
Status

```
<?php 
require ("Database.php");
class Status
{
    private 
    $sessionId,
    $db;

    public function socialStatus()
    {
        $db = new Database;

        $query = "SELECT  f.followingId, s.postDate ,s.status, u.username, u.profileImgPath, u.username, s.statId 
        FROM followers AS f
        JOIN status AS s ON s.userId = f.userId 
        JOIN users AS u ON u.userId = :sessionId
        WHERE s.userId = :sessionId AND f.followingId = :sessionId ORDER BY postDate DESC";   
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);  
        $stmt->bindValue(':sessionId',  $_SESSION["userId"]);    
        $stmt->execute();   
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

Reply

```
<?php 

class Reply
{
    private 
    $sid,
    $db;

    public function socialReply()
    {
        $db = new Database;
        $sid = (isset($_POST['sid']) ? $_GET['sid'] : null);
        $query = "SELECT s.statId, r.reply, r.dates, u.username
                  FROM replies AS r
                  JOIN status AS s ON s.statId = r.statId 
                  JOIN users AS u ON u.userId = r.userId
                  WHERE s.statId = :sid
                ";   
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);  
        $stmt->bindValue(':sid',  $sid);    
        $stmt->execute();   
        return $stmt;
    }

}
```

Output

```
    <div class ="socialContent">
        <div class="socialShare">
            <form class="shareStyle" id="social">
                <ul class="socialImagesControl">
                    <li>
                        <label for="file-upload">
                            Add picture
                        </label>
                        <input type="file">  
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="file-upload">
                            Add Album
                        </label>
                        <input type="file">  
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <label>
            <textarea class="socialStart" placeholder="Share your news" name="messages"></textarea>
            <span class="error"></span>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Enter" class="socialSubmit">
            </form>
        </div>
</div>

<div class ="socialStatus">
<?php

require ("classes/Status.php");
require ("classes/Reply.php");
$status = new Status;
$replys = new reply;
$results = $status->socialStatus(); 
foreach($results as $status){
  ?>
  <input type="text" name="sid" value="<?php print $status["statId"]; ?>">  
<div class="reports">
        <ul>
            <li class="reportRight"><input type='checkbox'  style='display: none'  class="reporting"  id=reportings><label for=reportings>&#x2026;</label>
            <div class="reportlist">
                <ul class="reportPosition">
                    <li>spam</li>
                    <li>abuse</li>
                </ul>   
            </div>        
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <figure>
        <a href="index.php"><img src="<?php print $status['profileImgPath'];?>"></a>

       <figcaption><a href="index.php"> <?php  print $status["username"]; ?></a></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <div class="usermessage">

   <pre><?php 
   print $status["status"]; ?></pre>
    <div class="times">Posted<?php  print " " . $status["postDate"]; ?></div>
    </div>

   <div class="answers">
   <div class ="socialStatusAnswers">
   <?php
    $answers = $replys->socialReply(); 
    foreach($answers as $ars){
    ?>
<div class="reports">
        <ul>
            <li class="reportRight"><input type='checkbox'  style='display: none'  class="reporting"  id=reportings><label for=reportings>&#x2026;</label>
            <div class="reportlist">
                <ul class="reportPosition">
                    <li>spam</li>
                    <li>abuse</li>
                </ul>   
            </div>        
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <figure>
       <a href=""><img src="assests/images/coffee.jpg" alt="Picture of a cup of coffee"></a>    
       <figcaption><a href=""><?php print $ars["username"]; ?></a></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <div class="usermessage">
        <?php print $ars["reply"]; ?>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="socialShare">
            <form class="shareStyle" id="replying">
                <ul class="socialImagesControl">
                    <li>
                        <label for="file-upload">
                            Add picture
                        </label>
                        <input type="file">  
                    </li>
                </ul>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>      
            <input type="text" name="sid" value="<?php print $status["statId"]; ?>">    
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
            <textarea class="socialStart" placeholder="Add a comment" name="addComment"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Enter" class="socialSubmit">
            </form>
        </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: dont test POST and GET, you should know which you are using

Comment: `$_POST['sid']` should be `$_GET['sid']`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Hit it on the nose, except that his alteration of the comment ruined it as explained by nogad. Also `$stmt->execute([':sid' =>  $sid]);` will save a line of code. And my recomendation is never, ever to use `CapItaLizeD` letters on a file include / requirement. It will bite you one of these days and is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Xorifelse To be honest, it looks more like a typo to me, `isset()` followed by the value in a ternary doesn't seem like a test for different methods.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of security when I did it, I guess looking at it now, it doesn't make much sense

Comment: @jeroen I wanted to comment that `isset()` can take multiple args, but then I fully understood your comment. 100% correct, however using multiple args acts like a `&&` operator, as `isset()` only returns 1 bool. So it makes sense doing it like that, but hardly recommended. (Seems like a Dutch name though)

Comment: You execute a statement, but you never fetch the results.

Comment: @Progrock Read the code, he does. He returns the stmt and uses it on request. He might be doing it in `socialStatus`. However it is inclear.

Comment: @Xorifelse, I read this: `$results = $status->socialStatus(); foreach($results as $status){`, there is no fetch here as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you aren't actually fetching any rows after you execute your queries.  Assuming you are using PDO try something like the following to return all rows from your query:

```
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

return $results;
```

Otherwise you are trying to iterate on a returned PDO statement.

Turn exceptions on for PDO to help in debugging, and check your error logs/display errors.

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Also adjust your functions to accept and use a parameter of say id.  This will make your code easier to test.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer, thanks you put me on the right tracks

Answer (score -1):

Check this line of code:  `$sid = (isset($_POST['sid']) ? $_GET['sid'] : null);`

Comment: As already explained by @nogad, NEVER EVER use `$_REQUEST`. You, the PROGRAMMER should know which **specific** input is required. One of these days `$_REQUEST` will be depreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote however. In essence it does resolve the problem. So I'd say +1. On the otherhand it does show outdated practises, so -1. So @IonutIsac unless you update the answer to an alaborate and up to date answer it will unlikely be upvoted.

Comment: Hello Xorifelse, your comment makes sense, I was just trying to make it easier for him when I suggested that, I am not sure that `$_REQUEST` will be deprecated soon, I will need to take more than before suggesting answers, to be honest I haven't used plain PHP for a long time.

Comment: but how much does your answer differ from first (deleted) comment. An answer should fix the issue, you're saying PHP is the cause. While a POST is much better then a GET. Focus on answering the question on HTML basis instead.